Transversal QLDPC Code Confusions
I have a few rudimentary questions about QLDPC codes.

Do any admit transversal Paulis? My intuition is that many such constructions are CSS, they should. But it's hard to see if this is obviously true.

Do HGP codes admit transversal CNOT? Because it seems that FT CNOT can be achieved by code deformation (https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.07424) and some transversal gates can be achieved with some partitioning technique (https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.10812). But I thought all CSS codes admit a transversal CNOT?




The Pauli operators of any stabilizer codes are transversal. By "transversal" I mean the logical operator can be written as a tensor product of single (physical) Pauli operators.

This is a very nice question and there is some tricky word-use there. In $[[n, k]]$ HGP codes, we have multiple ($k$) logical qubits encoded within the same code block made of $n$ physical qubits. The condition of CSS codes only guarantee you the transversal implementation of block-wise CNOT, but not the CNOT between the logical qubits within the same block. Block-wise means that you implement the CNOT gates for each pair of qubits between two code blocks. You must do the gates for all logical qubit pairs.


For example, the well-accepted $[[4, 2, 2]]$ code encodes two logical qubits into a block of four physical qubits. Assume we have two blocks $A$ and $B$ and therefore four logical qubits $A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2$. The canonical transversal CNOT between the two blocks will do
$$
CNOT^{\otimes 4} = \overline{CNOT_{A_1, B_1}} \overline{CNOT_{A_2, B_2}}.
$$
But what if you wanna do a CNOT gate between $A_1$ and $A_2$ within the same block? Luckily, the $[[4, 2, 2]]$ code has very good property and allow us to implement it with a SWAP gate(here for reference), but for the general HGP code, it's not really straightforward to see how the inner-block CNOT can be done.

I think in general if you want to perform logical gates within the same block, people resort to gate teleportation. Except for some special cases, such as [4,2,2] or [8,3,2] you can implement logical CNOT through other transformations like you mentioned. So I guess this is an outstanding problem ...

Thanks for the response—I trust then that d-dimensional color codes that can transversally implement the d \ d-1th level of the Clifford hierarchy are not Pauli stabilizer codes?
The block-transversality definition is interesting. I was a little bit confused on whether that was indeed how it was defined. Thanks!

@usermm $d$-dimensional color codes are still Pauli stabilizer codes.
